# How to fade in/out on a Tkinter Frame

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How can you fade in and/or out on a Tkinter.Frame or any other widget for that matter. All of the examples that I have seen have been for either root (Tkinter.Tk) or Toplevel setting the alpha e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22491808/1552953

Is it possible to apply this to an individual widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it on individual widgets. Transparency in Tkinter is only available for instances of `Tk` and `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Bryan's answer I came up with this solution, which he inadvertently provided most of the code for also.

One thing to note is if you move the main window the toplevel doesn't move with it...

```
import Tkinter
import Queue

class Flash(Tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, **options):
        Tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, root, width=100, height=20, **options)

        self.overrideredirect(True) # remove header from toplevel
        self.root = root

        self.attributes("-alpha", 0.0) # set transparency to 100%

        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.update_me()

    def write(self, message):
        self.queue.put(message) # insert message into the queue

    def update_me(self):
        #This makes our tkinter widget threadsafe
        # http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm
        try:
            while 1:
                message = self.queue.get_nowait() # get message from the queue

                # if a message is received code will execute from here otherwise exception
                # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156766/placing-child-window-relative-to-parent-in-tkinter-pythons
                x = root.winfo_rootx() # set x coordinate of root
                y = root.winfo_rooty() # set y coordinate of root
                width = root.winfo_width() # get the width of root
                self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x+width-self.winfo_width() ,y)) # place in the top right cornder of root

                self.fade_in() # fade in when a message is received
                label_flash = Tkinter.Label(self, text=message, bg='black', fg='white', padx=5, pady=5)
                label_flash.pack(anchor='e')
                self.lift(self.root)

                def callback():
                    label_flash.after(2000, label_flash.destroy) # destroy the label after 5 seconds
                    self.fade_away() # fade away after 3 seconds
                label_flash.after(3000, callback)

        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        self.after(100, self.update_me) # check queue every 100th of a second

    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399882/having-trouble-with-tkinter-transparency
    def fade_in(self):
        alpha = self.attributes("-alpha")
        alpha = min(alpha + .01, 1.0)
        self.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
        if alpha < 1.0:
            self.after(10, self.fade_in)

    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491488/how-to-create-a-fade-out-effect-in-tkinter-my-code-crashes
    def fade_away(self):
        alpha = self.attributes("-alpha")
        if alpha > 0:
            alpha -= .1
            self.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
            self.after(10, self.fade_away)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.minsize(700, 300)
    root.geometry("700x500")

    flash = Flash(root) # create toplevel instance

    def callback():
        # put a delay between each message so we can check the behaviour depending on the lenght of the delay between messages
        import time
        flash.write('Hello World')
        time.sleep(1)
        flash.write('Ready!')
        time.sleep(2)
        flash.write('Steady!')
        time.sleep(4)
        flash.write('Go!')

    # create a thread to prevent the delays from blocking our GUI
    import threading
    t = threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    root.mainloop()
    exit()
```