# Fade widgets or pictures in and out - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[How to fade in/out on a Tkinter Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806669/how-to-fade-in-out-on-a-tkinter-frame/27807437)
This question shows that you cannot use Tkinter's default transparency to fade in and out using widgets. However, is there any other way, using PIL or otherwise, to fade widgets (or pictures) in Tkinter in and out? (i.e. adjustable transparency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a (hopefully) simple answer:

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Image Fading")
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        self.load_pictures()
        self.fadetime = 1 # time between alpha channel changes in ms
        self.fadestep = 5 # change to alpha channel
        self.curstep = 0 # the current step through the transparency

        self.im = None # to hold the raw picture
        self.photo = None # to hold the tk compatible picture

        self.after(self.fadetime, self.fade_in)

    def fade_in(self):
        if not self.im:
            self.load_picture()
        alpha = min(self.curstep * self.fadestep, 255) # clamp to 255 maximum
        self.im.putalpha(alpha)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.label.configure(image=self.photo)
        self.curstep += 1
        print('fade in: %i' % alpha)
        if alpha == 255:
            self.curstep = 0
            self.after(3000, self.fade_out) # wait three seconds then fade out
        else:
            self.after(self.fadetime, self.fade_in)

    def fade_out(self):
        alpha = max(255 - self.curstep * self.fadestep, 0) # clamp to 0 minimum
        self.im.putalpha(alpha)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.label.configure(image=self.photo)
        self.curstep += 1
        print('fade out: %i' % alpha)
        if alpha == 0:
            self.curstep = 0
            self.im = None
            self.index += 1 # to use next picture
            if self.index >= len(self.filenames):
                self.index = 0
            self.after(3000, self.fade_in) # wait three seconds then load next picture
        else:
            self.after(self.fadetime, self.fade_out)

    def load_picture(self):
        while True:
            file = open(self.filenames[self.index], mode='rb')
            try: # if errors opening file as image, ignore and try next one
                self.im = Image.open(file) # this is a lazy operation and only reads image header
                self.im.load() # force image load here
                file.close() # close the file
                print('loaded: %s' % self.filenames[self.index])
                break
            except:
                file.close()
                self.index += 1
                if self.index >= len(self.filenames):
                    self.index = 0

    def load_pictures(self):
        self.filenames = []
        for file in os.listdir():
            if file.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] not in ['db', 'py', 'pyw']:
                self.filenames.append(file)
        self.index = -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

this assumes you wanted to fade each image out and then the next in rather than fade straight from one to the next.
be aware that doing this kind of fade in/out although done in the simplest way (using `putalpha`) is still cpu intensive due to the conversion to an `ImageTk` instance on each itteration.
thats why i have put variables for alpha stepsize and time to allow control over how many times it needs to be called.

if my assumption was wrong and you need to fade from one straight to the next it would be even more intensive as you would need to 'blend' the images together after applying an alpha channel to each image, then convert the result into a `ImageTk` instance